# Does setting higher refresh rate than monitor officially supports result in faster perceived refresh rate?

Tags: display

I've been reading articles about high framerate displays, about how some of them cheat and don't actually work at 120/144hz, and also about software that seemingly fixes those problems. Most software just sets the framerate from 60, as it was before the new display was connected, to whatever maximum it now has.

Above that I've found [some info](https://teksyndicate.com/node/134989) on increasing graphics card update rate. Supposedly it should improve perceived update rate on a display that doesn't support as many fps as the tool would say it shows. For example, people say that 74hz on a 60hz display looks smoother than before. I can't objectively test it myself, and I don't know much about the technicalities of that. How truthful is that? Is it just the placebo effect, or is there some sort of non-v-sync'ed tearing from converting 74 frames down to 60 which seems smoother?